# Is there a way I can make a dummy variable for multipule varaibles? Trying to have "White"|"White British"| "White Other" as 1 and anything else as 0

Tags: r

I tried this;

```
new_data $Ethnicity_dummy = as.numeric(new_data$Ethnicity == "White"|"White British"| "White Other")
```

but I get this error message;

```
new_data $Ethnicity_dummy = as.numeric(new_data$Ethnicity == "White"|"White British"| "White Other")
Error in new_data$Ethnicity == "White" | "White British" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

Comment: Try: `new_data$Ethnicity %in% c("White", "White British", "White Other")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the "or" (`|`) function incorrectly - if you wanted to use the or notation, you would have to specify the variable for each time (i.e. `new_data$Ethnicity == "White"|new_data$Ethnicity =="White British"...`)

A much easier way is `%in%` - try using:

```
new_data$Ethnicity_dummy = as.numeric(new_data$Ethnicity %in% c("White","White British","White Other"))
```